# Large pySpark DataFrame: .collect() is crashing even after .limit

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, limit, collect

I'm working with pyspark 2.1.1.

I created a PySpark DataFrame with a `sqlContext.sql('select...')` on a spark cluster which is to big for .collect() or .toPandas().

Since I want to use it in smaller parts with pandas I first just want to work on a really small part of it in pandas to test some code.

I tried several combinations of .limit(), .cache(), collect() and .toPandas() all crashed my sparkContext and/or caused an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

E.g. although the Dataframe does only have 3 small columns: this code is causing an OutOfMemoryError:

```
test = psdf.limit(5).cache()
test2 = test.collect()
```

It seems like .limit() is not really working as I expect.

How may I extract a small part of the table with pyspark which is really just a small part with which I may work really fast?

Comment: Can you try and use a `limit` clause on your input query?

Comment: The data you were reading in was an overload for your memory constraint

Comment: Yes I can, I did and it worked. But I want to do some more operations with pyspark on the whole data set before I pick a small part of the data to work with it in pandas. If I would do all these preparations with sqlContext.sql the code would look very ugly. By the way: I thought that pyspark operations are calculated on the spark/hive-cluster. But maybe I'm wrong. Are just the sqlContext.sql operations done on the cluster and the pyspark operations are done on my local machine?

Comment: I tried some more things. The problem is not the .limit().
The problem is that the query did a group by. If I'm doing the sql-querry with dbeaver directly on hive and then do import the result the ".limit()" works as expected. (Without limit I get a outOfMemoryError; with not)
Therefore it seems the sqlContext.sql is doing the group by on the local machine.